# Spring Data Rest 2.1.0 Cannot POST or PUT Complex Resource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-data, spring-data-rest

EDIT: This appears to be happening with PUTs as well.

Using spring-data-rest-webmvc version 2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT I have found that I am unable to POST a resource with a relation pointing to an already existing resource. I have 2 such entities which require references to be instantiated and POSTing to either of their endpoints results in the behavior below.

POSTing a resource without required references works well.

I did a bit of digging and it appears that `PersistentEntityResourceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` finds the `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` just fine, but it ends up throwing an exception while checking whether the `ObjectMapper` can deserialize the type. The cause of the exception is a `NullPointerException`.

example POST w/ relations to /reservations:

`{
"description" : "test_post",
"dateMade" : "2014-03-03T08:04:44.293-0600",
"timeLastChanged" : null,
"userLastChanged" : null,
"courseTypeId" : null,
"numCredits" : null,
"instructor" : null,
"numParticipants" : null,
"reservationType" : "MCU",
"status" : "REQUESTED",
"abstract" : null,
"requestor" : "http://localhost:8080/users/2",
"submitter" : "http://localhost:8080/users/2",
"conferences" : []
}`

RESPONSE:

`{
cause: null
message: "No suitable HttpMessageConverter found to read request body into object of type class domain.Reservation from request with content type of application/json!"
}`

POST w/ no relations to /roomGroups:

`{
"description" : "All Rooms",
"isOffNetwork" : false,
"roomGroupType" : "STANDARD"
}`

RESPONSE:

`201 Created`

Is there something wrong about the JSON I am POSTing which is resulting in an NPE from the `ObjectMapper`? Is there a workaround of some kind? This was working for me in 2.0.0.RC1 using a slightly different scheme for including reference links in the JSON and since the version of the Jackson dependencies appears to have stayed the same I wonder what is causing this issue...

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE:

This issue now *seems* un-related to the associated entities...

I created a new `@Entity` ConnectionRequest as follows:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "CONNECTION_REQUEST_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "FROM_ENTITY_ID", nullable = false)
private Long fromId;

@Column(name = "TO_ENTITY_ID", nullable = false)
private Long toId;

@Convert(converter = EntityTypeConverter.class)
@Column(name = "FROM_ENTITY_TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
private EntityType fromType;

@Convert(converter = EntityTypeConverter.class)
@Column(name = "TO_ENTITY_TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
private EntityType toType;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name = "CONFERENCE_ID", nullable = false)
private Conference conference;
```

I can POST a new ConnectionRequest record with a Conference relation included in the json as such `{"conference" : ".../conferences/1"}`.

I am however still getting the same exception w/ this `@Entity` Reservation:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "RESERVATION_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 50, nullable = false)
private String description;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "DATE_MADE", nullable = false)
private Date dateMade;  

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "TIME_LAST_CHANGED")
private Date timeLastChanged;

@Column(name = "USER_LAST_CHANGED")
private Integer userLastChanged; // TODO why is this an int?

@Column(name = "ABSTRACT", length = 2000)
private String _abstract;

@Column(name = "COURSE_TYPE_ID")
private Integer courseTypeId;

@Column(name = "NUMBER_OF_CREDITS")
private Integer numCredits;

@Column(name = "INSTRUCTOR", length = 255)
private String instructor;

@Column(name = "NUMBER_OF_PARTICIPANTS")
private Integer numParticipants;

@Convert(converter = ReservationTypeConverter.class)
@Column(name = "RESERVATION_TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
private ReservationType reservationType;

@Convert(converter = StatusConverter.class)
@Column(name = "STATUS_ID") 
private Status status;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name="REQUESTOR_USER_ID", nullable=false)
private User requestor;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name="SUBMITTER_USER_ID", nullable=false)
private User submitter;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "reservation", cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE})
private Set<Conference> conferences = new HashSet<>();
```

I'm not sure what's special about this class that's causing things to go awry...

Comment: Any chance you add the relevant parts of the domain model as well? Feel free to skim through the [test case|https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/jpa/DataRest262Tests.java#L85] added for DATAREST-262 and see how it differs from your setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the following:

Both of the non-postable entities had a property called `_abstract` due to it being a reserved word in Java. I had named the getter and setter for this property `getAbstract()` and `setAbstract()` respectively.

Jackson appears to have been throwing a null pointer exception since the getter and setter did not match the property name as expected.

When I changed the property name to `resvAbstract` and updated the accessors to `getResvAbstract()` and `setResvAbstract()` everything came together and started working.

I'm still curious about the change that led to this issue showing up, but I'm glad it's working!

Comment: please accept your answer as the correct one, so we can easily see the issue has been solved. See [accepting answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). ;)