# Save related entities spring data rest HAL-JSON

Tags: json, spring, rest, hateoas, hal-json

I have the follow problem

I have a basic configuration of spring data rest (Nothing fancy, nothing custom).

Using spring-data-rest-webmvc 2.0.0 RELEASE and spring-data-jpa 1.5.0 RELEASE

Class A

```
@Entity
public class A {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id

   private String name;

   @ManyToMany
   private List<B> b;

   // getters setters
}
```

Class B

```
@Entity
public class B {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id

   private String nameb;

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "b")
   private List<A> a;

   // getters setters
}
```

Repository A

```
@Repository
@RestResource(rel = "a", path = "a")
public interface ARepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<A, Integer> {

}
```

Repository B

```
@Repository
@RestResource(rel = "b", path = "b")
public interface BRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<B, Integer> {

}
```

When I save an entity works fine, but I don't know how to save a relationship

e.g. save an "A" inside a "B" using http

This is the last thing I try from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13031580/651948

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/a

{
    "name": "Name of A",
    "b": {
        "rel": "b",
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/b/1"
    }
}
```

I get an 201 http code but doesn't save the entity.

Did someone tried this already?

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I'm having a similar problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try just using the URL.

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/a
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name" : "Name of A",
    "b": "http://localhost:8080/api/b/1"
}
```

or, in your case, it's probably

```
"b" :  ["http://localhost:8080/api/b/1"]
```

because A.b is a list and hence you submit an array. Did not test this, though.

This should be the valid way since Spring 2.0 (see [Spring Data Rest 2.0.0.RELEASE Breaks Code Working Previously With RC1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22097646/spring-data-rest-2-0-0-release-breaks-code-working-previously-with-rc1#comment33577957_22111435)) and it works for me well.