# REST Hateoas, managing CRUD on a ressource

Tags: rest, hateoas

**Context**

I m actually developping a simple application in which I need to use REST level 3 HATEOAS.

I m having two entities :

- User
- Billing

I need, when I add a billing, to reference the user inside of it.

**Questions**

What are the informations I should send to my backend, from my frontend app, to add the hateoas reference, inside the billing ressource, concerning the user ?

I mean, inside the body of the request, should I send the url of the user ressource ? Or should I send the id of the user, and then making an url discovering to get the real user url ?

Comment: You could take a look at the accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879975/spring-data-rest-uri-vs-entity-id although it is Spring, but relates to HATEOAS in general.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding how HATEOAS works.  With HATEOAS the client should never have to know any urls.  Instead, the server responds with any urls that are valid.  In a truly RESTful service the client should only have to know 1 url.  It should be able to navigate to any point from there. [Here's](https://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS) a very simple explanation.  I would personally recommend looking at one of the existing HATEOAS specifications like my personal favorite [SIREN](https://github.com/kevinswiber/siren).

Comment: In you reply, you tell that the client should never know url, and then that server sends valid url to client. I m misunderstanding this point :-/. Actually, my problem is not for displaying valid links, it's, how should I do to post data and reference it through links ? Should I send the full url ? Or only the Id, and then I make some jobs to manage this ?